# API maps exibir endereço

Tags: javascript, api, maps

Hoje em meu sistema estou exibindo como ponto de referência dados já cadastrados no sistema com base na latitude e longitude. Gostaria que o script encontrasse a referência fornecida pela própria API do maps, apenas eu fornecendo a latitude e longitude atual.
Aguardo.

preciso exibir o endereço na variavel $html, todo o restante do código está ok:

```
<?php
$html .= "<td>".exibir aqui endereço."</td>";
 ?>


<script language = "javascript">
function GetAddress() {
var lat = parseFloat('$lat');
var lng = parseFloat('$lon');
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
'latLng': latlng
}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
if (results[1]) {
  alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address);
}
}
});
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=pt-br) *(veja Reverse Geocoding)*

[Neste link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Reverse-Geocoding-Get-address-from-Latitude-and-Longitude-using-Google-Maps-Geocoding-API.aspx) há um **DEMO** do que você quer, vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: Entendi, só não consegui aplicar em meu script, se puder me ajudar:

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. Qual o problema? Tem algum plunkr ou local pra ver o código?

Comment: Atualizei com mais detalhes a pergunta inicial. Se puder me ajudar, agradeço muito.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido o problema desta forma, porém identifiquei que a mesma posição (latitude e longitude) informam diferentes endereços em cada consulta, será um bug da API ou algo errada no script?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lat = parseFloat(<?php echo $RS["vl_latitude"]; ?>);
    var lng = parseFloat(<?php echo $RS["vl_longitude"]; ?>);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                meuEndereco = 'Location: ' + results[1].formatted_address;
            }
        }
    });
</script>     
<?php
  $enderecosEmJavaScript = "<script>document.write(meuEndereco)</script>";
  $html .= "<td>".$enderecosEmJavaScript."</td>";
 ?>
```